# Magento 1.9.3 Automatically generate pdf file of new orders

Tags: pdf, magento1.9.3, order-confirmation

In Magento, we can manually create a order confirmation in **PDF** file in admin. I would like to make this happen **automatically**. So every time a customer has placed an order, I would like Magento to create a **PDF file of the order confirmation**, and place it in a **certain folder** on the server.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to create invoice automatically ?